# Parse User Login Facebook without ParseUI Android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, parse-platform

I want to implement a user Login just with Facebook on my own witouth using the ParseUI.

Here is what I did:
Main Screen checks if ParseUsers == null
If ParseUser ist null it redirects to the LoginActivity.

For this activity I just want to show the Login with Facebook Button.
And thats my Question:
If I use the provided tutorial from Facebook  and use the xml Code:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
android:id="@+id/login_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

The Facebook sdk is used to login and not the Parse SDK which creates a Parse User and likes it.

My Question now is where do I get the Facebook Button from? Do I need to create a simple Button with the Facebook Login image or is it possible to use the Facebook button as described without calling the Facebook login routine automatically and instead just call my own onClick function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer in the [ParseUI-Android sample project](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android). They do it using a [regular button](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android/blob/master/ParseLoginUI/res/layout/com_parse_ui_parse_login_third_party_section.xml):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/facebook_login"
    style="@style/ParseLoginUI.Button.ThirdPartyLogin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/com_parse_ui_small_vertical_spacing"
    android:background="@drawable/com_parse_ui_facebook_login_button_background_selector"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/com_parse_ui_facebook_login_logo"
    android:text="@string/com_parse_ui_facebook_login_button_label"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

To which they attach an [`onClickListener`](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android/blob/master/ParseLoginUI/src/com/parse/ui/ParseLoginFragment.java#L292)

```
private void setUpFacebookLogin() {
    facebookLoginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (config.getFacebookLoginButtonText() != null) {
        facebookLoginButton.setText(config.getFacebookLoginButtonText());
    }

    facebookLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loadingStart(false); // Facebook login pop-up already has a spinner
            if (config.isFacebookLoginNeedPublishPermissions()) {
                ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithPublishPermissionsInBackground(getActivity(),
                config.getFacebookLoginPermissions(), facebookLoginCallbackV4);
            } else {
                ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(getActivity(),
                config.getFacebookLoginPermissions(), facebookLoginCallbackV4);
            }
        }
    });
}
```